# transparent comboBox in Powershell

Tags: forms, powershell

Need help. Want to make transparent comboBox for my Form, but don't know how.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$comboBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$comboBox.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(200, 30)
$comboBox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 10)
# What to write here for transparent?

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$result = $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What do you mean transparent: with no border? Or actually showing the content underneath? Is it just `.Background = Transparent` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

`PowerShell ComboBoxs` do not support transparent background colours.

When I use `SAPIEN's PowerShell Studio` to try and create a transparent `combobox`, I get the the following error:

[image]

But you can set the `combobox` to any other colour you like.

Comment: From MSDN: To give your control a transparent backcolor. Locate the constructor for your control class. The constructor appears in the control's code file. In C#, the constructor is the method with the same name as the control and with no return value. In Visual Basic, the constructor is the method named New.
Call the SetStyle method of your form in the constructor.                            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);                  this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;